# How is multiplication in Libfixmath performed?

Tags: c, batch-file, cmd, fixed-point

I am porting the library mentioned by Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libfixmath in CMD Batch.

The library uses an Q16.16 format.

I am trying to port it in Q16.16 or Q15.15 format.

What I can't understand is in the part of the code in fix16.c.

The multiplication in the hardware case that supports 32bit.

```
fix16_t fix16_mul(fix16_t inArg0, fix16_t inArg1)
{
    // Each argument is divided to 16-bit parts.
    //                  AB
    //          *    CD
    // -----------
    //                  BD  16 * 16 -> 32 bit products
    //               CB
    //               AD
    //              AC
    //           |----| 64 bit product
    int32_t A = (inArg0 >> 16), C = (inArg1 >> 16);
    uint32_t B = (inArg0 & 0xFFFF), D = (inArg1 & 0xFFFF);
    
    int32_t AC = A*C;
    int32_t AD_CB = A*D + C*B;
    uint32_t BD = B*D;
    
    int32_t product_hi = AC + (AD_CB >> 16);
    
    // Handle carry from lower 32 bits to upper part of result.
    uint32_t ad_cb_temp = AD_CB << 16;
    uint32_t product_lo = BD + ad_cb_temp;
    if (product_lo < BD)
        product_hi++;
...
```

A, B, C and D are numbers at 16bit.
My questions is In the calculation of the carry I do not understand how it does.
It takes ad_cb and makes the shift, that is, it takes the 16 low bits of AD_CB and moves them upstairs and adds them to BD.
The third operation I can't understand.

```
if (product_lo < BD)
        product_hi++;
...
```

Can you explain it better? How is it related to the previous ones?

Partial Porting:

```
:fix15_mul F1 F2 Ret

setlocal

    set "F1=%1"
    set "F2=%2"

    set /A "A=F1>>15, C=F2>>15"

    set /A "B=F1 & 0x7FFF, D=F2 & 0x7FFF"
    
    set /A "AC=A*C, AD_CB=A*D + C*B,BD =B*D"
    
    set /A "product_hi = AC + (AD_CB >> 15)"
    
    rem Handle carry from lower 30 bits to upper part of result.
    set /A "ad_cb_temp=AD_CB << 15, product_lo = BD + ad_cb_temp"

    set /A "product_lo2 =(AD_CB & 0x7FFF)<<15"

    if %product_lo% lss %BD% set /A "product_hi+=1"

    set /A "return=(product_hi << 15) | (product_lo >> 15)"

( endlocal & set "%3=%Return%" )

goto :eof
```

EDIT: *One Focus only*

Comment: I too had noticed that a+b could not be less than one of the two. There are actually other dark spots in the code as well. Should I ask more questions in your opinion? As for the test you say needs to be done with decimal places, I'll try to do it and if it reveals anything I'll report it here. Regarding the fact that the topic has been covered in other questions, I don't know how to find them. You can help me?

Comment: other questions: for example the calculation of ad_cb can overflow and is not taken into consideration

Comment: I might change library. Do you know a well-made popular one?

Answer (score 1):

I'll try and explain and provide a sample annotated modified code below (untested) which I think might work.

```
fix16_t fix16_mul(fix16_t inArg0, fix16_t inArg1)
{
    // Each argument is divided to 16-bit parts.
    //                  AB   *    CD
    // -----------
    //                BD  16 * 16 -> 32 bit products
    //               CB
    //               AD
    //              AC
    //             |----| 64 bit product
    int32_t  A = (inArg0 >> 16),    C = (inArg1 >> 16);
    uint32_t B = (inArg0 & 0xFFFF), D = (inArg1 & 0xFFFF);
    
    int32_t AC = A*C; // worst case bounds -2^15*(2^15-1), 2^30
    int32_t AD = A*D; // worst case bounds -2^15*(2^16-1),(2^15-1)*(2^16-1)
    int32_t BC = B*C; // ditto. The sum of these two terms could overflow 
    uint32_t BD = B*D; // bounds 0 .. (2^16-1)^2
    
    int32_t product_hi = AC + (AD >> 16) + (BC >> 16);
    
    // Handle carry from lower 32 bits to upper part of result.
    uint32_t ad_bc_temp = (AD << 16) + (BC << 16); // as unsigned
    uint32_t product_lo = BD + ad_bc_temp;
    // these are both now unsigned ints so that when adding together
    // if an overflow occurs then product_lo < BD
    if (product_lo < BD)
        product_hi++;   // so we increment the product_hi
    ...
```

"the carry I do not understand how it does. It takes ad_cb and makes the shift, that is, it takes the 16 low bits of AD_CB and moves them upstairs and adds them to BD. The third operation I can't understand."

It relies on the unsigned int value of BD always becoming smaller in the event of a carry occurring (and that only one carry is possible here). I suggest you validate this code against a few of the awkward edge cases comparing against a computation done in full int64 arithmetic. Values 0x8000ffff and 0x7FFFFFFF are obvious stress tests. It is easy to make a careless slip that only affects a handful of edge cases when doing this stuff.

Comment: I thank you. I award you the bounty. Tomorrow I'll check more thoroughly and I'll have some questions for you.

Comment: Do validate that it works correctly. I don't have time to do that right now. I'm still a little worried by the overflow when ad_bc_temp is computed. I'm not so sure now that a carry there cannot affect the result. A suitable set of test patterns to make sure it performs ok are 0x0000, 0x0001, 0x0002, 0x8000, 0x8001, 0x8002 and the compliments after xor 0xffff. Each one used in low and high word slots.  If it can get those right in any permutation it is very probably correct. If you are paranoid then add a walking ones test and a walking zeroes test for good measure.